# Need to declarate some field @Nullable inside api interface method

Tags: android, retrofit, nullable

I am working on api's in 'Android App' using retrofit library to make restfull.

now I have a method I need to declrate some fields as nullable fields, so the user maybe choose to select this option to filter result or not.

### my field is 'int' type. I declare the method like that:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("filter_products")
Call<Parts> getProducts(@Header("Cookie") String sessionIdAndToken,
                        @Field("category_id")  int category_id);
```

I need to put the category_id as nullable field.
how I can do that?

> > @Nullable @Field("category_id")  int category_id

and

> > @Field("category_id") @Nullable  int category_id

sure is not correct..

any help please?

and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` is the primitive type, and is not a nullable value. Use `Integer` instead:

```
@Nullable @Field("category_id") Integer category_id
```